# jQuery - Passing an .on events' delegated elements' scope to the event.data object

Tags: jquery, events, scope, this

I would like to pass the delegated DOM element that was clicked to the `.on` `event.data` property...

So, something like:

```
$('.parent-element').on('click', '.delegated-element', { self: $(this) }, function(e) {
  console.log(e.data.self);
  // Logs:
  //   $(document)
  // I want:
  //   $('.delegated-element')
});
```

Is there any real way to achieve this?

I fear not, but thought I'd ask. =)

**PS**: Just to be clear, I know that I can simply use $(this) within the event itself, but for what I'm trying to achieve it would help to be able to pass the scope around.

Comment: Have you tried e.target?

Comment: @Dream_Cap - I'm looking to get the scope in to the event.data. My problem can be solved in other ways, I'm just wondering if what I'm asking for is possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

The event handler is bound before anything is clicked, so you can't get the clicked element before it's clicked, and pass it in as data, it doesn't work that way.

Inside the event handler, you can get the clicked element with `event.target`, or the element the event handler is bound to with `this`, or even the delegated target with [`event.delegateTarget`](https://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/)

Simply put, you can only pass in something you have access to before the event handler is even created as event data, you can't pass in something that isn't known until the event handler is bound, and someone triggers it.

Comment: "The event handler is bound before anything is clicked" - Can I force this to update somewhere within the click event?

Comment: Doesn't really matter if you can "update", or trigger an event or whatever, you still won't be able to get the clicked element before someone actually clicks it. You could of course get all elements matching the class `.delegated-element`, but you won't be able to know which one triggered the event handler before you even created the event handler.

Comment: I understand. The click handler is fired when the event is triggered. The data object that's passed to the `.on` function is created and assigned when the click handler is instantiated. The chicken can't come before the egg, basically... Oh well, that's a shame. Thanks. =)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. You don't know what the clicked element is, before someone actually clicks it.